# A phone call notification simulation using ionic framework

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to send a push notification from server to an ionic client and show this notification in client like a phone call (mobile device should play a sound and show 'Accept' or 'Reject' buttons with caller information). It should work if mobile app is not running or in background, that's why I decided to use FCM messages.

```
this.storage.get('firebase_token').then((token) => {
  console.log('Orders get firebase token and call register. Token: ' + token);
  this.agentService.registerPushNotifications(token, () => {
       this.firebase.onNotificationOpen().subscribe((notification) => {

           // How to open the app and show the page with a ringtone ??

       });
  });
});
```

How can I open the app and show the call page with a ringtone in incoming push notification? Or maybe there is a better way for this kind of feature.

Comment: What you are asking for is not possible, that is not something a push notification can do. IONIC cannot do something like that

Comment: @AhmadAlfy The process is like that: Person A sends an offer to Person B. And Person B gets an alert and a page of incoming offer with Accept/Reject buttons. PersonB's application can be not running or in background mode. How this feature can be done with ionic framework? Thanks in advance

Comment: You can send a regular push notification and when the user open it redirect him to a page inside the application asking him to approve or disapprove.

Comment: I've already implemented it like that, but it looks not so good, because Person B can miss a notification. But in case of a ringtone/caller page it will be shown to Person B for few seconds with an alert. But it seems it is an impossible feature with Ionic. Thank you

Comment: Shame on me, I already added the answer :(

Comment: You should have a look on https://github.com/Taracque/ionic-plugin-callkit . It might be doing what you're looking for :)

Comment: This is the only reason to move out from ionic

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for (the same format like a phone call) isn't possible with Ionic. You can however redirect the user to a view inside the application where you ask him to take action.

Take the following example for push notification. In app.components.ts I initialize this function when the platform is ready

```
  initializePushNotifications() {
    let pushObject = this.push.init({
      android: {
        senderID: 'Your ID Here',
        icon: 'logo'
      },
      ios: {
        alert: true,
        badge: false,
        sound: true
      },
      windows: {}
    });
    if (!pushObject['error']) {
      pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((data: RegistrationEventResponse) => {
          // Whatever you want to do
      }, err => {
        console.log('Couldnt register:', err);
      })
      pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((data: any) => {
        let self = this;
        // When the user click the push notification
        if (!data.additionalData.foreground) {
          switch (data.additionalData.entity_type) {
            case 'takeAction':
              this.openView(data.additionalData.user_name, data.additionalData.id);
              break;
              ......
          }
        }
      });
      pushObject.on('error').subscribe((e: any) => {
        console.log(e.message);
      });

    } else {
      console.error(pushObject);
    }
  }
```

See, in the pushed message we add an object under the key `additionalData` where you can pass whatever you want. You can pass something like `entity_type` with the value `takeAction`. When the user click it, you can open a new view and pass additional parameters like the name of the user and the id of the entity or whatever.

On this screen you can open an alert asking the user to click yes or no and based on his input you fire the correct request.

**Note**

I know this is different from what you were asking for but your request cannot be fulfilled using Ionic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I am using the latest version of Ionic. It seems your version is for Ionic 1.

Comment: Nope, that's ionic 2 and typescript